# Is “handsome” associated with masculinity and “pretty” associated with femininity?

Tags: connotation, grammatical-gender

**TL;DR**— See title:

- Are the attributes in  “handsome girl” and “pretty boy” perfectly interchangeable?
- Is there an implicit, gender-specific connotation in “handsome” (♂) and “pretty” (♀)?

---

[**This video**](https://youtu.be/XF1UMFqho9A?t=262) called my attention for the first time to
the none-analogy of those two German words:

- [*dämlich*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/d%C3%A4mlich) (“stupid”, literally *lady-ly*)
- [*herrlich*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/herrlich) (“magnificent”, literally *mister-ly*)

<sup>*(Both do actually have a surprisingly different etymology.)*</sup>

The presenter assumes that *däm-lich* was some sort of feminine version for *herr-lich* and cites,

> ***like how in English, the word “handsome” is often associated with something that is masculine, and “pretty” with something that is feminine.***

**Is this true?**

Does it sound weird to call a manly man “pretty” or a beautiful, feminine woman “handsome”?

Do English native speakers assume gender in consequence of the usage of either?

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17108/can-you-still-call-a-woman-handsome

Comment: also related. [What is the female equivalent for “handsome”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/107714/what-is-the-female-equivalent-for-handsome) and [“Beautiful” for boys?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/272090/beautiful-for-boys) and [Would you use the term “looker” to describe a man?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/149956/would-you-use-the-term-looker-to-describe-a-man?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Finally, [Meaning of 'pretty man'](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/342104/meaning-of-pretty-man) I think if you read the links, you'll reach the conclusion that *pretty* and *handsome* are not interchangeable for men. Whilst *beautiful* and *pretty* are close synonyms.

Comment: The links provided by Josh and Mari-Lou pretty much cover the question except for one usage I didn't spot.  "Pretty boy" is used as a derogatory term for a man who is overly vain about his appearance or is physically attractive but that's the only thing he has going for him.

Comment: Oh, I obviously should have done more actual research on ELU itself rather than trying to infer from a foreign language’s fallacy. Thanks anway, that’s quite some batch of related questions, while they don’t actually seem to address the *implied* gender of the words in question.

Comment: *[Emma](http://austen.com/emma/ch1.htm) Woodhouse, **handsome**, clever, and rich, with a comfortable home and happy disposition, seemed to unite some of the best blessings of existence; and had lived nearly twenty-one years in the world with very little to distress or vex her.*  Though admittedly that tells us relatively little about current usage.

Comment: Answered at [Can you still call a woman "handsome"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17108/can-you-still-call-a-woman-handsome)

Comment: But when I was in Ol Virginia, North Carolina I did go. There I spied a handsome lady. Oh her name I did not know. (A verse from "In Old Virginia", collected by Cecil Sharp in Callaway VA in 1918.)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, calling a man "pretty" or a girl "handsome" sounds awkward and would be seldom used.  I cannot think of a single instance of hearing a female called "handsome."  In general, saying that a man is "pretty" implies that he has feminine characteristics or is said jokingly.

Comment: Randall, did you see the quote by @verbose Jane Austen's Emma in the comments above or the ELU link by @Edwin? 'handsome' for women, while not the most common, has a long history. Pragmatically, calling a woman handsome means she is good-looking but by implication not traditionally pretty/beautiful (otherwise you'd have used one of those words).

Comment: Handsome is almost never used in that context in modern spoken English, at least in the U.S., regardless of the history of the word's usage.

Answer (score 3):

According to [LearnersDictionary.com](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/can-the-word-handsome-be-used-for-women):

> While handsome is more often used for men, women can also be called
>   handsome. When a woman is described as handsome, it suggests that she
>   is very good-looking, and also healthy and strong. Handsome is less
>   likely to be used to describe a woman who is petite or delicate.

The term is *dated and rarely used in today's English* according to [The Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Handsome%20Woman).

The [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/83926?rskey=rhZiNu&result=1#eid) has this to say of handsome to describe a woman:

> Of a person (occas. an animal): attractive and pleasing in appearance,
>   esp. in having a well-proportioned figure and noble bearing; (now)
>   spec. (of a woman) striking, stately, as opposed to conventionally
>   beautiful or pretty

The OED has four quotations that refer to a woman, admiringly, as handsome; one from 1622, one from 1718, one from 1855 and the latest from 1908.  **My advice is not to use handsome to describe a woman; the danger of being misunderstood is too great.**

As for pretty man, instinctively I say ***no!***, but a Korean drama subtitled in English might signal a change.  See [DramaFever](https://www.dramafever.com/drama/4340/Pretty_Man/):

> The prettiest man in the world is on a mission to seduce 10 different
>   rich and powerful women for his own ambitions. But one adorable and
>   poor girl with a huge crush on him just might change all of that.

Comment: Justin Bieber could be described as pretty.

Comment: So you would generally advise *against* using either “handsome woman” or “pretty man”, and instead stick to some of the less ambiguous attributes of attractiveness?